# Adding totals of functions

Tags: javascript

My total_price function is not working. I want it to be put on the totalPrice paragraph that i've already did but it doesn't show.

```
function calcAdult()
{
    var ticketPrice = 12;
    var amount = document.getElementById('SAinput').value;
    var total = ticketPrice * amount;
    document.getElementById('SAPrice').innerHTML = "Cost = $" +total.toFixed(2);
    return total;
} 

function calcCon()
{
    var ticketPrice = 10;
    var amount = document.getElementById('SPinput').value;
    var total = ticketPrice * amount;
    document.getElementById("SPPrice").innerHTML = "Cost = $" +total.toFixed(2);
    return total;
}   
function total_price()
{
    var price = calcAdult() + calcCon();
    document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = "Cost = $" + price.toFixed(2);            
}
```

Comment: who is calling total_price?

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: seems fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pLujrptt/2/

Comment: nothing is calling it..should I run the total_price function when the page loads?

Comment: You need to call it... in the fiddle it is called on the button click... when to call it will depend on your use case

Comment: The subtotal is shown automatically after you type a number (i used onchange). This part works fine but showing the total price doesnt seem to work.

Comment: <input id="SAinput" value="0" name="SA" type="number" min="0" max="10"  onchange="calcAdult()"> this code calculates the subtotal instantly after you put a number. I also want the total price to do this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pLujrptt/3/ - call `total_price` instead of `calcAdult`

Comment: yes i want it like this but how are you calculating the total priceswhen you didnt even call calcAdult and calcCon?

Comment: Because `total_price` is calling both of them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments in the discussion, you are not calling the `total_price` method at all, instead you are calling the other 2 methods on change of the field values.

Instead you can just call the `total_price` method on change of the values like

```
<input id="SAinput" onchange="total_price()"/>
<input id="SPinput" onchange="total_price()"/>
```

then

```
function calcAdult() {
    var ticketPrice = 12;
    var amount = document.getElementById('SAinput').value;
    var total = (ticketPrice * amount) || 0;
    document.getElementById('SAPrice').innerHTML = "Cost = $" + total.toFixed(2);
    return total;
}

function calcCon() {
    var ticketPrice = 10;
    var amount = document.getElementById('SPinput').value;
    var total = (ticketPrice * amount) || 0;
    document.getElementById("SPPrice").innerHTML = "Cost = $" + total.toFixed(2);
    return total;
}

function total_price() {
    var price = calcAdult() + calcCon();
    document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = "Cost = $" + price.toFixed(2);

}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pLujrptt/)

Comment: Thanks Arun I got it to work..I had a lot of typos that's why most of my code did not work. Thanks for help again.